# Splitting edges in PostGIS for network analysis

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I'm trying to use PostGIS and pgRouting to do some walking distance analysis, using pgr_drivingdistance. I can get this to run without a problem. However, there are only a limited number of nodes on my network. Sometimes, there are over 1km between nodes and I only want to explore 300 and 500m of walking distance. A typical example is below from OSM where a path (marked in yellow) is over 500m in length with no nodes. If I run the example below, the path in yellow is excluded because the distance between nodes is too great.

[image]

Is there a way to split edges over a certain length to create additional nodes, given that there a lots of edges like this in my dataset? I can get a list of all edges over a certain length. That's fine. But where next? I see PostGIS offers various functions such as addNode, TopoGeo_AddPoint, ST_NewEdgesSplit and ST_ModEdgeSplit but I'm not sure which, if any, of these I should be using. I've not been able to find a clear example, especially where there are lots of edges to split based on a distance between nodes measure. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Adding nodes to the graph seems to be the logical solution, but it can ever only *slightly* improve robustness - you will face the same issue eventually. Instead, consider this: every *edge* that is connected to one of the returned *nodes*, and that is **not in the returned *edge* list** already, can be traversed at least partially! How far those can be traversed is determined by comparing the difference between `agg_cost` of the respective *node* and the desired `distance` value. I can't seem to find any of my own implementations for this problem right now - but this is the way to go!

Comment: If you do the same analysis in QGIS with the network tools there, it should be possible without modifying any nodes. You can e.g. use a 1 km line with just 2 vertices (start- and end-point), take a point in the middle of the line and create service area for say 200 meters - works perfectly, creating 200 m to both sides, without reaching any node of the network. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @Babel - thank you but I need a non-QGIS solution. My PostGIS is running on a Linux server via the command line. Sorry I should have said

Comment: geozelot - I sortof see what you're getting at. So let's say I have the nodes that work ok. But additionally, there are the missed edges which have nodes that are too far away. You're saying I should use agg_cost minus distance to capture these? I'm not really sure how I would achieve that though.